# LLVM equivalent of gcc's __BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__?

Tags: gcc, cross-platform, llvm, memory-alignment

GCC provides a `__BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__` pre-defined macro which is the largest alignment ever used for any data type on the target machine you are compiling for. I cannot seem to find an LLVM's equivalent for this. Is there any? If not, what is the best way to figure it out (preferably with pre-processor)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't accessible from the preprocessor, but `__attribute__((aligned))` or `__attribute__((__aligned__))` (with the alignment value omitted) will give the alignment you want.  This is supposed to give the largest alignment of any built-in type, which is 16 on x86 and ARM.

For example:

```
$ cat align.c
struct foo {
  char c;
} __attribute__((aligned)) var;
$ clang align.c -S -o - -emit-llvm
...
@var = global %struct.foo zeroinitializer, align 16
```

This is used by unwind.h for _Unwind_Exception:

```
struct _Unwind_Exception
{
  _Unwind_Exception_Class exception_class;
  _Unwind_Exception_Cleanup_Fn exception_cleanup;
  _Unwind_Word private_1;
  _Unwind_Word private_2;

  /* @@@ The IA-64 ABI says that this structure must be double-word aligned.
     Taking that literally does not make much sense generically.  Instead we
     provide the maximum alignment required by any type for the machine.  */
} __attribute__((__aligned__));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in llvm internals as TargetData::PointerABIAlign, but it doesn't appear to be exposed to code. I'd just hard code to 16 bytes, as it seems like it'd be a while before we see any more aligned types or instruction sets.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. You suggested exactly what I did — hardcoded to 16 :-)